# Serving html from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, javascript

I am hosting some client-side HTML files through Dropbox.  I would like to make them more sophisticated, but I don't know how far I can go.

Is there a document describing what functionalities can a client-side HTML for Dropbox have?

To give you an example, I just separated the javascript from my HTML and put it in an external .js file.   Dropbox apparently doesn't like it, as though it can't recognize the external .js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that anymore, if you're on the Basic plan.

> Dropbox Basic (free) users: Beginning October 3, 2016, you can no longer use shared links to render HTML content in a web browser. If you created a website that directly displays HTML content from your Dropbox, it will no longer render in the browser. The HTML content itself will still remain in your Dropbox and can be shared.
>
> Dropbox Pro and Business users: Beginning September 1, 2017, you can no longer render HTML content.

from https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

Answer (score 0):

Try **inspecting the site and checking the path** to the `.js` file.

A short google search brought up [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/4-ways-to-host-your-website-on-dropbox/).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.